# Installing new hard drive in 2010 27" iMac & hdd fan control

Tags: imac

I just want to know if I install a new hard drive without a temp connection like the default apple installed drives, do I need to do anything with the unused temp connection cable/wire in the iMac?

I'm going to using HDD fan control to control the fan, but am wondering if I have to disconnect the temp connection cable from anything else on the iMac??